# What is the word for the stuff we use in a coffee shop such as coaster, straw, TA cup and its lid...?

Tags: single-word-requests

I hope you guys can help me with the word and teach me how to find it in other occasion.
Thank you very much!

Comment: may we have an example sentence please, as that really does affect the words you get. English being such a rich language.

Comment: Coffee shop paraphernalia.

Comment: are you including sugar packets, creamers, and I the like amongst the items you're asking about? if so, then the answer would be different from one describing "tableware" only

Comment: What’s a TA cup?

Comment: Starbucks crap, if you are drinking coffee through a straw.

Answer (score 1):

**Tableware** is probably the best word: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableware) defines it as "the dishes or dishware used for setting a table, serving food and dining. It includes cutlery, glassware, serving dishes and other useful items for practical as well as decorative purposes". The [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tableware) defines it as "the knives, forks, spoons, plates, glasses, etc. used for meals". Such terms are more commonly used for sit-down meals than takeaway coffees, but the general terminology is the same, covering both the vessels (cups, plates, spoons, etc) and the tools (cutlery: spoons, coffee stirrers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In the industry, you'd refer to these things as [**disposables**](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/restaurant-disposable-supplies.html) implied in the name is that these are items that get used and thrown away (or hopefully recycled).

If you're speaking of reusable items that don't walk out with the customer, then you'd call these *tableware* (see StuartF's answer) [*drinkware*](https://www.crateandbarrel.com/dining-and-entertaining/drinkware/), etc.